# Overfitting (?) of Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm currently trying to do some gaussian process regression with a covariance function that looks like this:

$$k(t,t') = \sigma\exp(-\alpha |t-t'|)$$

I'm using MATLAB's `fitrgp` function to train this model and get the model predictions. The "problem" now is that the noise is estimated to really low values so that my model fit looks really spiky and hits about every datapoint approximately exactly.

Is this considered to be normal because I used a covariance function that leads to non-smooth trajectories? I come from deterministic fitting and there this would ne considered severe overfitting. Or is this a problem with my choice of hyperparameters? As I understand it, hyperparameters are optimized in a single optimization run within `fitgpr` even when not using the'OptimizeHyperparameters' option. Is that correct?

I'd really appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Maybe I should add that the goal of my analysis is to compare the likelihood of two gaussian process models with different covariance functions on my dataset.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! Gaussian processes are prone to overfitting (especially with small data sizes).  I would suggest using a sum of white noise kernel with your current one to see the performance. I am not much aware of fitrgp library but on a first look, it seems like 'OptimizeHyperparameters' is set to 'none' by default. You might try changing the parameters. If you are well versed with gaussian process literature, you could also see this presentation https://www.emse.fr/~leriche/op17_R_LeRiche_slides_v2.pdf optionally. Hope it is of any help.